# GWT compiling error at constructor

Tags: java, gwt, playn

I have little knowledge how GWT works, so can anybody help me here?
This is the full log when I use Eclipse to compile my [Playn](https://code.google.com/p/playn/) html project:

http://pastebin.com/0EXNe57a

The same error appears when I try to run the html version with Maven in Eclipse or command line. Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GWT is compiling your Java-Code to JavaScript and emulating the Classes and Methods you are using from the JRE. But GWT is not supporting all Classes and Methods of the JRE.

You can find a List of Supported Classes and Methods [on gwtproject.org](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html#Package_java_util).

In your case `java.util.Vector`is supported but not the methods `add(float, float)` and `set(float, float)`. So you should look for an alternative.

Note: The use of `java.util.Vector` [is not recommended](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) - regardless of working with GWT or not.

**Update:** Can't remeber that there ever was a method `add(float, float)` in `java.util.Vector`. Do you use that class or do you have an own `util.Vector`-Implementation?
If so you should check if your gwt.xml-file is including the source-path. Already [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8272208).

Comment: Yes the util.Vector class was actually my own. I added the util package to the source path and everything works fine! Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. And sorry for the wrong first answer. `util.Vector` confused me a little ;)